# Multiple Textinput message based on button on select

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

New to powerapps and looking for some help.

I want a Textinput1 box (in screen2) to display a date based on 1 of the 2 button selection(in screen1).

If Button1 is selected I want the Textinput1 box text to display `DatePicker.SelectedDate`.
If Button2 is selected I want the Textinput1 box text to display `Gallery2.Selected.DATE`.

I have tried various ways but not getting anywhere.

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a global variable in the OnSelect of the buttons, (the syntax is Set(VariableName, Value)), then set the default of your Textinput1 box to that variable. You may also want to try using a label control following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-date-picker

Comment: Thanx but that went no where.